# Node Express sever error : Can't render headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, server

I'm fairly new to this. I created a node-express server that runs locally. And I have a `index.html` under `public\html` folder. When I visit that index page, I got an error `Can't render headers after they are sent to the client node server error`. My understanding is that if the url is  localhost:8080 plus `/`, index.html will be rendered? How do I solve this problem? Many thanks!

ps: The odd thing is that when I move index.html out from the "public" folder to the same directory with the node server.js, and change to `app.get('/', function (req, res {fs.readFile('/index.html'..` the index.html seems to work fine.

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var http = require('http');
 var https = require('https');
 var request = require('request');
 var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
 var path = require('path');
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var certificate = fs.readFileSync( 'something.0.0.1.cert' );
 var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('something.0.0.1.key');

 process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
 app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('__dirname + '/public'+ '/html'+/index.html', function(error, content) {
    if (error) {
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.end();
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.end(content, 'utf-8');
    }
 });
     res.send('Hello World');  
});

https.createServer({
   key: privateKey,
   cert: certificate
 }, app).listen(8080,'0.0.0.0');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get one response for every request. Your code shows `res.send('Hello World');`

change this to `res.sendFile("__dirname + '/public/html/' + 'index.html' ")`

You can remove the fs.readFile line too.

The reason fs.readFile('/index.html') works when you move to the same file as your server is because that line means to read a file called index.html from the same directory. But you want to send a response to a request, not just read files.

Check out the docs on [res.sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) in express

Try this:

```js
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
         res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/html/'+'index.html'); 
    });
```

Comment: You mean remove the entire line `fs.readFile('__dirname + '/public'+ '/html'+/index.html', function(error, content) ` ? How to I tell it to read index.html but not other .html files then?